# Ruby Gem for File Downloads

Tags: ruby, rubygems, download

This is a somewhat unnessary question because it regards something that's painless to write yourself...but sometimes it's nice to use an existing Gem anyway.

Is there a gem that simply downloads URLs I ask for and keeps track of the local copies (and maybe even remote changes) in a little database and gives me a nice object to access it all through?

Sort of a download manager in Ruby?